# jQuery Ready Event Not Working After AJAX Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Excuse me...

Found any answer there and still didn't works.

So there is my scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.gifs').gifplayer();
});
```

And dynamic content loaded by AJAX:

```
<img class="gifs post img-responsive img-bordered" width="100%" src="<?php echo $post->thumb_url;?>" data-gif="<?php echo $post->url;?>" />
```

Image with class "gifs" should called "gifplayer" function. But everytime ajax loaded, it wont works. What I should do to get a best implementation for this?

That's all and thank you...

Comment: Use something like `$.ajax( /* ... */ ).done(function() { $('.gifs').gifplayer(); /* ... */ });`

Comment: Thank you. My code posted in comment because text limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time the dynamic content is added to the DOM by AJAX, the code in the Ready event has already been executed.

You should be calling $('.gifs').gifplayer() only after the AJAX call has completed successfully.  In jQuery, that would be through the .done or .success event handlers.

Here is a jQuery example:

```
$(function() {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    $.get( "test.php" )
    .done(function( data ) {
        $('.gifs').gifplayer();
    });
}
```

If you are making multiple AJAX calls or have non-ajax-loaded .gifs elements, you'll have to get a bit more elegant to make sure gifplayer() is only called on them once.

Comment: Answered in comment. It's mean I must call function after ajax success executed? Will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$('.gifs').gifplayer();
```

Will only execute `gifplayer()` on elements found by jQuery *at that time*.  The line of code is only executed once, when the page is ready, and never again.  jQuery has no way of identifying elements which don't exist yet.

When you add more elements to the page, you need to execute that code again.  If you shouldn't re-execute for the same elements then you'll want to modify your jQuery selector to identify only the new ones.

Comment: I have a JS custom file, and I wont adding js script into ajax loaded element. Any better implementation?

Comment: @UnapzeusAdinovic: It doesn't matter what file defines the functionality.  You can still execute the code.  No, there is no "better implementation".  In order to initialize this plugin (I assume that's what this is), you need to invoke the `.gifplayer()` function on matching elements.  You can abstract it behind some callbacks and functions and events, but the bottom line is that when you have an `img` tag and you want to invoke `.gifplayer()` on that tag, there's no other way than to, well, invoke `gifplayer()` on that tag.